Interactive Brokers - API for Implied Volatility Comparison chart
Does anybody know a way how to download data from Implied Volatility Comparison chart from Interactive Brokers TWS? Is there any API method (either REST API or TWS API) for that?

Or do you know any other source of this data?
Generally, I am looking for a historical data of stocks implied volatility.
Thank you for any ideas.

So in the end I've been able to get the data through a simple Node.js script using node-ib module and this code:
// Stock
ib.reqHistoricalData(
  1,
  ib.contract.stock('AMZN'),
  '20240530-12:00:00',
  '365 D',
  '1 day',
  'OPTION_IMPLIED_VOLATILITY',
  1,
  1,
  false
);

Full (and ugly draft) code can be seen here: https://gist.github.com/junajan/8a92dcb068af400e899ad27625533f07
